# sharePoint arcitecture customisation

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i created a new custom list in sharepoin 2010, with some couple fields, 
when i go into my site , click site action then site setting , then on my list it shows.

near the title of the items in the list , there is a div of class"s4-ctx", that is hidden that shows on hover, that is a drop down list that shows some options like : view items , edit items, delete item and other thing...
My question is how can i customize that options that shows , as per example i want to add another option as send item by email, how can i do that ...where from , and how and where can i add the code that i want it to execute when clicking this botton...
thx

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom list actions using SharePoint Designer - here's a pretty nice tutorial http://gvaro.wordpress.com/2009/12/19/adding-custom-actions-to-the-list-item-menu-in-sharepoint-2010-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/